# Google Ads Conversion Actions Not Showing Up

Tags: android, google-apps-script, branch.io

Hoping to get some help here.  We've got Branch.io installed and for some reasons we aren't seeing our conversion actions being updated in Google Ads conversion actions.  We have branch linked under linked accounts for both Android and iOS and it is showing in branch as active.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QxJz.png)

Any suggestions or ideas?  I tried re-importing new conversion actions with no success.

Answer (score 0):

For Google adwords integration, once you have enabled it via logging in on your branch app dashboard via your Google ads admin access, you would need to insert the linked ids for Third party app analytics > Branch.
Once setup, you would need to map the branch events to respective Google ads events under the event config tab for the ad partner setup.
Similarly, the branch events would also be needed to be imported on the Google ads dashboard and added to 'Include in Conversions' as YES if you want to optimise your campaigns on them.

If you would like us to check deeper on authenticating the integration from our end, please reach out to support@branch.io and we will gladly help setup the integration with you.

Also, sharing our doc here for your reference : https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/enabling-google-ads-integration